# AutoCad .net project using Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-code, autocad, autocad-scripts

I was trying to figure  out if it is possible to set and debug a vb.net/C#.net AutoCAD project using VS Code? Sorry if this is  a silly question but I do not have extensive experience in this area. So far I've been able to follow tutorials, set and develop a project using VS Community but couldn't find any guidance on how to do it with VS Code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Visual Studio Code isn't Visual Studio, it's completely different. You can't use tutorials made for one to learn how to use the other. There are a *lot* of tutorials about Visual Studio Code. If you google for `visual studio code debugging` the very first result should be [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiHke638Z_oAhXO0KQKHeNQDdgQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.visualstudio.com%2Fdocs%2Feditor%2Fdebugging&usg=AOvVaw0L79mzgvXAGPG76wBUIUIG)

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a Test Bench?

Comment: Let's reverse the question and ask "Why not?" What have You done, and what is the problem? as I know and maybe I'm wrong it should be possible.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your anser. I can see that these two are completly different softwares so I cannot use the tutorials from one to work with another. That is actually the reason  I asked my question here. Unfortunately my basing on my current  knowledge I was unable to find too much useful information for this excercise.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the answer,  I believe I was not clear enough. I want to be able to build/compile the project to get the .dll file that I can load to the Autocad and use the functions defined in a code

Comment: @CADDeveloper, thanks for your reply. I am a begginer in coding and  to be honest I started doing  that to improve functionality of AutoCAD (Civil 3D) on the  projects I am working on. I was following the tutorials and basing on the API developers reference guide was able to introduce some of my ideas using VS Community.
With VSCode I am able to start the VB.NET Project(I dont know how to set  application type to WPF Class Library - this is  what I've done in VS Comminity),add the references but I do not know how to modify the json files to run the project. I was hoping someone already did it

Answer (score 2):

Got it working with vscode and Acad2021. The example works with the following setup:

To get debugging working with full .net framework I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271098).

1. create a new project with: dotnet new classlib
2. change your csproj file to (Note: for different autocad versions different versions of the nuget packages will be needed):

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
       <PropertyGroup>
           <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
           <RootNamespace>ProjectName</RootNamespace>
           <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
           <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
           <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <ItemGroup>
           <PackageReference Include="AutoCAD.NET" Version="24.0.0"></PackageReference>
           <PackageReference Include="AutoCADCommands" Version="2020.0.0"></PackageReference>
       </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
3. set your launch.json to:

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": ".NET Core Attach",
               "type": "clr",
               "request": "attach",
               "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
           },
       ]
   }
   ```
4. change the Class1.cs file to:

   ```
   using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
   using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
   using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

   namespace AU.KO_WT_TestPlugin
   {
       public class Initialization : IExtensionApplication
       {
           [Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.CommandMethod("MyFirstCommand")]
           public void cmdMyFirst()
           {
               Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
               ed.WriteMessage("\nI have created my first command.");
           }
           void IExtensionApplication.Initialize()
           {
           }

           void IExtensionApplication.Terminate()
           {
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. run the command: dotnet build
6. open autocad
7. in autocad run the netload command and load your newly generated dll under PathToProject/bin/debug/net48/ProjectName.dll
8. back in vscode press F5 to start debugging
9. select the acad.exe process
10. set breakpoint in your c# code
11. in autocad call the command MyFirstCommand
12. debug away

Notes:

- as .net assemblies can't be unloaded in autocad after changing your code and recompiling it with dotnet build, it is necessary to restart autocad and netload the new assembly
- It should be possible to create a task that launches autocad and netloads the assembly through a script. I haven't found time to explore that possibility